# Ajax browser refresh in background

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser, refresh

i am trying to produce a browser refresh in the background after a click.

My issue is i am allread using ajax to process other element on the page but i need these to be updated.

```
// approved - allready approved section

$('.allready_approved').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();                 
    $('#main_bloc_approved').slideUp();

    // i need to perform a browser refresh here but without reloading the page here???

     $('#main_bloc_allready_approved').fadeIn();                    
     return false;


     return false;
});

$('.approved').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();             
    $('#main_bloc_allready_approved').slideUp();

     // i need to perform a browser refresh here but without reloading the page here???

     $('#main_bloc_approved').fadeIn();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: so why not just make an ajax call there and pull in your new data?

Comment: what do you mean by "browser refresh" ? What do you need to be "refreshed" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use, unless I have misunderstood you :)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('body').load(window.location.href,'body');
});
```

also convert your `.click (...)` into `.live('click',...)`

also you have `return false;` twice which is only needed once really.

Not that I wanna be technical about this but,

(number of clicks + number of unnecessary bytes) * number of users =  better think of another way e.g. `.setTimeout()` to update every minute to save some bandwidth or you will go bankrupt before you care to think :) but thats my opinion and not a fact :)