# refresh a page continiously through jquery for certain time gap

Tags: php

I have a custom control kept inside a div that changes its contents only on refresh, so I am thinking to use something that can refresh only the div.I am trying to do  face book wall like concept.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296815/ajax-browser-refresh-in-background

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- For ease i'm just using a JQuery version hosted by JQuery- you can download any version and link to it locally -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#responsecontainer").load("response.php");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  $("#responsecontainer").load('response.php?randval='+ Math.random());
 }, 9000);
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="responsecontainer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval to continuosly perform an action. clear it with clearInterval(intv);

```
var intv = setInterval(function(){
 //do stuff here every 5 seconds
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(intv);
}, 30000);
```

Above will do something ever 5 seconds, then cancel the polling after 30 seconds.

Comment: thanks for your reply @chovy , but my page i dieing.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you paste a jsfiddle?

Comment: got it chovy !solution is to do a database connection with pooling, and that's how face book ticker is working.Suggestions on that please...do you know any scripts like that floating around.